# Zero Down Time Deployment Node.js/NGINX Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a React/Node.js application running on a single server using docker-compose. I'm trying to achieve a 0 downtime deployment for my react app. The process right now, does a webpack build (replaces the files in my dist folder) and then docker down and docker up. This whole process takes about 2-3 minutes.

I realized that with docker-compose I can scale my container up/down but I'm not sure how to only push my code to 1 of them, rebuild the webpack and npm restart it then kill other containers. I really don't want to use Kubernetes/Swarm or Openshift since it's a bit of overkill. I'm wondering if anyone else has achieved something similar to this.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
node:
    build:
        context: ./env/docker/node
        args:
            - PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/app
    image: react_app:rapp_node
    command: "npm run prod"
    expose:
        - "3333"
    networks:
        - react-net
    volumes_from:
        - volumes_source
    tty: false

nginx:
    env_file:
        - ".env"
    build:
        context: ./env/docker/nginx
    volumes_from:
        - volumes_source
    volumes:
        - ./env/data/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
        - ./env/docker/nginx/sites/node.template:/etc/nginx/node.template
    networks:
        - react-net
        - nginx-proxy
    environment:
        NGINX_HOST: ${NGINX_HOST}
        VIRTUAL_HOST: ${NGINX_VIRTUAL_HOST}
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${NGINX_VIRTUAL_HOST}
        ESC: $$
    links:
        - node:node
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/node.template > /etc/nginx/sites-available/node.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

volumes_source:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
        - ./app:/var/www/app
```

And my nginx is something like this:

```
server {
server_name www.${NGINX_HOST};
return 301 ${ESC}scheme://${NGINX_HOST}${ESC}request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

root /var/www/app;

location / {
proxy_pass http://node:3333;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade ${ESC}http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host ${ESC}host;
proxy_cache_bypass ${ESC}http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Comment: why do you do `down` you can just `build` images and then `docker-compose up -d` and it will create only those new contianers

Comment: @MazelTov because I need to basically kill the running node server and npm start again. if you look at my node container it's running a script that handles that. I'm not making any change to my Node.js image so it doesn't need to be rebuilt. We are just making react changes

Comment: then you can do just `docker-compose restart node`, but if you do `down` it will remove network, stop all containers and so on

Comment: my opinion is that you should build your image with code inside and not mount code folder to the same container.

Comment: @MazelTov I'm gonna try the restart node and let you know.  What do you mean by building image with code inside? Do mean I shouldn't use the volume?

Comment: i prefere my production image to be tested before deployed, and when it was deployed to be secure as possible. That is why i build my images in gitlab-ci, then test the image, and then deploy it and the code is always in the image, not mounted... maybe this approach would be "overkill" for you too

Comment: technically you can restart each scaled container separately because they are named `foldername_container_1` but your nginx always pick randomly one of those containers named "node" so if you access the node during restart it will throw error i think

Comment: @MazelTov Thanks for the explanation. Your solution worked. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

faster way how to refresh container is

```
docker-compose restart node
```

because if you do `docker-compose down` it will bring all services down, remove configured networks.

If you have scaled service you might try to restart it with

```
docker restart foldername_node_2
```

and you could have 0 downtime, but the nginx configuration is not sufficient cause it will randomly select `node` machine, so you will have to implement some backup server

Comment: additionally you would want to set the `-t` value on restart otherwise it will use the default 10 seconds, so you could use something like `docker restart -t1 node` to reduce that to 1 second. (You might want some delay, so the exact amount depends on your situation.)